# Move deluxetable left into margins

Tags: tables, margins, document-classes, deluxetable

Is there a way to move a deluxetable left into the margins of the page? I am using the emulateapj document class and my table is too wide for the page.

Here's an example of my table with the data redacted.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{emulateapj}

\begin{document}

\section{Table}

\begin{deluxetable*}{lcccccccccc}
    \tablenum{1}
    \tabletypesize{\small}
    \tablecolumns{11}
    \tablewidth{0pt}
    \tablecaption{Title}
    \tablehead{
        \colhead{header0} &
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{header1} &
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{header2} &
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{header3} &
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{header4} &
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{header5}
    }
    \startdata
    data & data & data & data & data & data & data & data & data & data & data \\
    \enddata
    \tablecomments{comments}
    \label{table}
\end{deluxetable*}

\end{document}
```

I would like to avoid reducing the textsize or reducing the column spacing, as this would make reading the data more challenging.

Comment: You should be able to compile it.

Comment: When I compile this, the deluxetable uses the full width of the page.  Is that not what you want?  Is the question how to get it to use only one column, in which case it would be too narrow for the single column?

Answer (score 1):

With

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{emulateapj}


\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

\section{Table}

\lipsum[1-3]
\begin{deluxetable*}{lcccccccccc}
    \tablenum{1}
    \tabletypesize{\small}
    \tablecolumns{11}
    \tablewidth{0pt}
    \tablecaption{Title}
    \tablehead{
        \colhead{header0} &
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{header1} &
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{header2} &
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{header3} &
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{header4} &
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{header5}
    }
    \startdata
    data & data & data & data & data & data & data & data & data & data & data \\
    \enddata
    \tablecomments{comments}
    \label{table}
\end{deluxetable*}
\lipsum[4-12]

\end{document}
```

I get

[image]

Looks ok to me.